# selling apple stock limit order

Tags: stocks

Last night around midnight I saw the Brexit voted leave so I went to sell my Apple shares. I put a limit at 96.00. It ended yesterday closing at 96.10. Will my limit order be executed? I am confused on how that works

Comment: You have a higher chance of getting a fill if you make your order valid during the extended trading session (a.k.a. before- and after-hours). Your broker will have a "time-in-force" field when placing an order that you can set to "GTC + extended hours", which will make the order remain forever until cancelled, and allow execution during extended hours trading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your order may or may not be executed.  The price of stock can open anywhere.  Often yesterday's close is a good indication of today's open, but with a big event overnight, the open may be somewhere quite different.  You'll have to wait and see like the rest of us.  Also, even if it doesn't execute at the open, the price could vary during the day and it might execute later.

Comment: okay thank you Brick! hopefully it executes. Already down 3% in pre market :/